# Showing that the set of vectors are a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following set $W$ is a subspace of $P_2$:
$W$ = {$p(x) ∈ P_2  |  p(x)=(x − 1)(ax + b), a, b ∈ R$}

(a) Show that:

i. Every vector in $W$ has the property that $p(1)=0$.

ii. If $p ∈ P_2$ such that $p(1) = 0$, then $p$ can be expressed as $p(x)=(x − 1)(ax + b)$.

(Together (i) and (ii) show W = {$p(x) ∈ P_2 | p(1) = 0$}.)

(b) Show that {$x^2 − x, x − 1$} forms a basis for $W$.

(c) Show that $B$ = {$x^2 − x, x − 1, x$} is a basis for $P_2$.

Question 1a(i) is relatively easy but I really don't know what question 1a(ii) is asking for given what's done in 1a(i). For question b, I'm unsure how this is different than a basis for $P_2$. Is there a way to have those polynomials into a matrix then in RREF and determined linear dependence and whether it spans based on the rank?

Comment: I think you better explain in your question what exactly is meant by $P_2$. Also if you are talking about vectorspaces then you should mention the field that is involved.

Comment: For (ii) use the relationship between roots and factors. Remember the basic definition of linear independence - the only linear combination that gives zero is all coefficients zero and remember what it takes for a polynomial to be exactly zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $p \in P_{2}$ then $p(x)$ takes the form $a_{2}x^{2} + a_{1}x + a_{0}$. If $p(1) = 0$, then $p(x)$ takes the form $(x-1)(ax+b)$, so $p \in W$. This answers your first question. But $(x-1)(ax+b) = ax^{2} + (b-a)x - b = a(x^{2}-x) + b(x-1)$, so $\{x^{2}-x, x-1 \}$ is a basis for $W$. This answers your second question.